# Do mini glaciers reappear on the same spots in the next winter?

Tags: dont-starve

I haven't had the chance to live through summer yet, but I wonder if the locations marked with mini glacier icons on map will still point to them come next winter.

There are pengulls who are marked on map too, and they don't necessarily reappear in the same place, so I'd like to know if it's also a random spawn for mini glaciers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say "mini-glaciers" I assume you mean the small ice patch that appears beneath a colony of Pengulls in the Winter.

If so, the answer is no, the ice patches do not spawn in the same spot each Winter. During Winter, if you are walking near the ocean, a colony of Pengulls has a chance to appear. At the same moment that the Pengulls jump out of the water, an ice patch is created for them to go to. These ice patches are spawned in a random location.

During your next Winter, the next time you see a group of Pengulls begin to pop out of the ocean, pull up your map. Check around your location, and you should see the little Pegnull icon somewhat nearby. That location is where the ice patch has spawned, even though the Pengulls have not walked to it yet.

If you want some "official" verification, the [Don't Starve Wiki](http://dont-starve-game.wikia.com/wiki/Pengull) even says:

> Pengulls noisily spawn from the ocean when the player is nearby and walk directly to a **randomly spawned** "breeding ground", marked by a thin layer of ice, that will appear as soon as a flock spawns and is represented by a Pengull symbol on the map.

Answer (score -1):

no they do not reappear in the same spot after a year.

Comment: How do you know that?

Comment: Can you give any sort of proof or any way to verify your statement?

Answer (score -3):

Not to necro an old thread; but for anyone newly searching for this answer:
No, they do not respawn again ever. 
Details: From many hours spent in-game. And yes, talking about the "mini-glaciers" in RoG and not just the thin ice that form under pengulls.
However, ice is a renewable resource as each winter, as you walk around the ocean, it spawns the pengulls and they will form with 3-5 mini-glaciers at their location.
Unrelated: Best way to survive summer is by rotating two thermal stones in a snow chester.

Comment: There's a 3 year old answer saying the same thing.

Comment: There's no concept of "necroing" coz this is not a thread-based discussion forum but a questions and answers site. Posting answers whenever is encouraged. Except when you're repeating what has already been posted.